# Web Scraping in Javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap application atm and I want to scrape the HTML and JS off a web page using ajax. The page I'm trying to load dynamically adds the bus times to the page when its loaded and I want to get that data. This works if you use the Kimono API but its too slow

This will be client only with the web site that I'm scraping off being the server so I can't use node.js.

If dataType is set to 'script' then it goes into the success callback function but the data is undefined. If you change dataType to anything else like 'text' or 'html' it goes into the error callback function.

```
    $.ajax({
        //async: false,
        url: 'http://www.metlink.org.nz/stop/4922',
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error: " + error + " status:" + status + " xhr: " + xhr);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success");
            //var textNode = document.createTextNode(json)
            //document.getElementById("html").appendChild(textNode);
            alert(data);

            //$("#html").html("<text>" + json + "</text>");
        }
    });
```

Comment: you cannot do this without some type of server side help, as you will get an error because of cross domain policy.

Comment: Btw, this is the snippet it's loading: `http://www.metlink.org.nz/stop/4922/departures`. But yes, can't get it with AJAX it seems (cross domain). You'll need a proxy service.

Comment: In the ajax request setting cross domain to true suposeably solves this. This will eventually be run on phonegap with every domain set to a whitelist. I can scrape the site above if I use jquery .load but that just scrapes the site before its fully loaded so I can't set the list of times before its put onto screen.